# How to select akka actor with actorSelection?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am trying to select one actor which have already created. Here is a code:

```
val myActor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor]), "myActorName")
println("myActor path - " + akka.serialization.Serialization.serializedActorPath(myActor))
println("Selection from spec akka://unit-test/user/myActorName " + system.actorSelection("akka://unit-test/user/myActorName").resolveOne().value)
println("Selection from spec /user/myActorName/ " + system.actorSelection("/user/myActorName/").resolveOne().value)
```

The result is:

```
myActor path - akka.tcp://unit-test@127.0.0.1:46635/user/myActorName#1444872428
Selection from spec akka://unit-test/user/myActorName None
Selection from spec /user/myActorName/ None
```

Also I can pass a message to actor and it completes well.
What I missed during actorSelection? How to select actor properly?

**UPDATED**

It is very strange, but when I replace `system.actorSelection("/user/myActorName/").resolveOne().value`
with `system.actorFor("/user/myActorName/")` everything works. I mean `actorFor` returns an actor. (Which is not a right solution due to `actorFor` is deprecated)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please, be careful with futures. In your case you're receiving future which may be not completed at the calling moment - so its value may be empty:

```
scala> println("Selection from spec /user/myActorName/ " +   system.actorSelection("/user/myActorName/").resolveOne().value)
Selection from spec /user/myActorName/ None
```

vs

```
scala> val fut =   system.actorSelection("/user/myActorName/").resolveOne()
fut: scala.concurrent.Future[akka.actor.ActorRef] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7eb8d7bd

<just wait some time here>

scala> fut.value
res21: Option[scala.util.Try[akka.actor.ActorRef]] = Some(Success(Actor[akka://default/user/myActorName#1625966960]))
```

To obtain value correctly use onComplete or just `for`-comprehesion/`map`:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

for (res <- system.actorSelection("/user/myActorName").resolveOne()) {
   println(res)
}
```

Keep in mind that onComplete/for are implemented as listeners, so they might be executed in different thread. If you need the result in current thread - use classical [`Await.result`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html) (it's blocking - so, you should do it outside of actor's context/`receive`).

Comment: Very surprising :) I thought that `implicit timeout` in `resolveOne` is used to wait and provide the result.

Comment: Nope :). Scaladoc: "It is completed with failure ActorNotFound if no such actor exists or the identification didn't complete within the supplied timeout"

Comment: So timeout just used to complete or fail returned future, but you still have to process this future classical way